# detect the sprite from two points ( cgpoint ) sprite kit - swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, cgpoint

I'm making a game in SpriteKit .
I have a huge problem, I can not find online and even on the Apple website the method to be able to find a node between two locations ( CGPoint ) .
The method UiSwipeGesture you can not find the Swipe in any direction but only left, right, up, down .

So I found other methods (see code below ) to make a slide , but I can not find the way to understand there is some node between the two positions.

Someone can help me? thanks

Code here:

```
var locationBegan : CGPoint = CGPoint()
var locationEnded : CGPoint = CGPoint()
var objectbegan : SKNode = SKNode()    

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches 
    {
        let location: CGPoint! = touch.locationInNode(self)
        self.locationBegan = location
        var nodeAtPoint : SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        self.objectbegan = nodeAtPoint

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location: CGPoint! = touch.locationInNode(self)
        self.locationEnded = location
        var nodeAtPoint : SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        var finalDestination : CGPoint = GetFinalDestination(location, nodeAtPoint: self.objectbegan)
        nodeAtPoint.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(finalDestination, duration: 1))

    }
}
```

how find the node between locationBegan and locationEnded ?
Thanks

If this is not possible could you advise me a method to find the node in the swipe in all directions , not just left, right , up and down ? thanks

**UPDATE**
Set the node this properties for run:

```
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 5)
node.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have `SKPhysicsBody`s set on the nodes you want to find but, once you do, you can use `SKPhysicsWorld`'s [`bodyAlongRayStart:end:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/bodyAlongRayStart:end:).

`bodyAlongRayStart` returns a `SKPhysicsBody?`, so you'll have to unwrap it to use it. If you then need the `SKNode`, use the `node` property of `SKPhysicsBody` (which returns an `SKNode?`, so you'll need to unwrap that too). Use the `physicsWorld` property of your `SKScene` to call `bodyAlongRayStart`. If you combine calling that function and optional bindings, it would look something like:

```
if let physicsBody = scene.physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart(locationBegan, end: locationEnded) {
    if let node = physicsBody.node {
        /* do something with node here */
    }
}
```

If you're expecting there to be more than one `SKNode` along that line (which you probably are), then you'd use [`enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:end:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:end:usingBlock:) instead:

```
scene.physicsWorld.enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart(locationBegan, end: locationEnded) {
    (physicsBody, point, normal, stop) in
    if let node = physicsBody.node {
        /* do something with node */
    }
}
```

Comment: The only 3 possibilities I can think of are either: 1. You don't have a `physicsBody` set on your node; 2. The `physicsBody` of the node is offset from where you see the node in your view (this is actually fairly common); 3. The ray from `locationBegan` to `locationEnded` really doesn't intersect anything. One thing you can do to check this is to set the [`showPhysics`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/showsPhysics) property of your `SKView` to `true` so that you can see where the `physicsBody`s are.

Comment: Very Very Thanks, the problem is physicsBody on node.! Now Works

Comment: One last question , I have to make calculations based on the node that I picked up with the slide and the location of the last touch ( locationEnded ) .

My problem is that being a beginner I can not quite move into yet , so I would like to know how I can set the nodo.physicsworld that I found in a SKNode .

var node = self.scene ? .physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart ( locationBegan , end : location )
var nodeNow : SKNode = node ? .node

but I do not work and gives me an error, requires me to put on and remove ! at the end of the line.
thanks

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to clarify how to get and use the node from the `SKPhysicsBody`.